# Delete file extension Microsoft Sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, json-formatting, 2019, column-formatting

I need to process filenames and remove file extensions from them.
MS Sharepoint 2019 on board.
I've read docs about declarative syntax but no luck so far.
My point is that I need to process each file name and delete everything after dot.
Script that I tried to use:

```
    {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": {
                "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": ">",
              "operands": [
                "length(split(@currentField, '.'))",
                1
              ]
            },
            "split(@currentField, '.')[0]",
            "@currentField"
          ]          
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

That script does not show any errors but no changes for file names.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!